# Why rejection handler doesn't invoke when queue overflowed and all threads busy

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have read manual from java doc about `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

Lets see this part:

> **Rejected tasks**
>
> **New tasks submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable) will be
>   rejected** when the Executor has been shut down, and also **when the
>   Executor uses finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue
>   capacity, and is saturated.** In either case, the execute method invokes
>   the RejectedExecutionHandler.rejectedExecution(java.lang.Runnable,
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor) method of its
>   RejectedExecutionHandler. Four predefined handler policies are
>   provided:
>
> 1. In the default ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy, the handler throws a
>      runtime RejectedExecutionException upon rejection.
> 2. In ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy, the thread that invokes
>      execute itself runs the task. This provides a simple feedback
>      control mechanism that will slow down the rate that new tasks are
>      submitted.
> 3. In ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy, a task that cannot be executed
>      is simply dropped.
> 4. In ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy, if the
>      executor is not shut down, the task at the head of the work queue is
>      dropped, and then execution is retried (which can fail again,
>      causing this to be repeated.)
>      It is possible to define and use other kinds of
>      RejectedExecutionHandler classes. Doing so requires some care
>      especially when policies are designed to work only under particular
>      capacity or queuing policies.

To check bolded text I tried to write small example:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1),
                Executors.defaultThreadFactory(),
                new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                        System.out.println("rejected");
                    }
                });
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("work  started");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("work  finished");
            }
        };
        //execute
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(runnable);
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(runnable);
        threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
```

this code outputs:

```
work  started
work  finished
work  started
work  finished
```

I expected to see "rejected" output in console.

Can you explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1)` can hold one runnable.
Third call to `threadPoolExecutor.execute(runnable)` should give you expected result. Since first call was removed from queue immediately and 2nd call is held in queue until first `runnable` finishes executing.